# Insert a text value from Excel cell at a specific location in the Word document in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I currently have a variable say x which stores a cell value from Excel and I am trying to place x at (a,b) in the Word document.

I have used:

```
With objword.Selection
   .Rows.HorizontalPosition=a
   .Rows.VerticalPosition=b
   .TypeText(x)
End With
```

But this doesn't work - I get this error:

> Application defined or object defined error

I have a table that is at a different position on the table and they shouldn't be overlapping, but could this be the issue?  I tried using `.ParagraphFormat` instead but that doesn't really have a method for the coordinates

Comment: "...doesn't work" - how so? Do you get an error? Does it not do the position you want, does it just skip that line entirely?  Also, how do you declare `a` and `b`?

Comment: I get the following error " application defined or object defined error" ; a and b were just used here in the question as a reference, in my code the positions have been hard coded

Comment: I assume you get that error at the second line?  Is `objWord.Selection.Rows` a valid use in Word VBA? (I'm not too familiar with Word VBA, so am just making sure) and not perhaps something like `objWord.Selection.Table`?

Comment: The intellisense tool built into VBA doesn't show an error with selection.rows; but does with the latter

Comment: I tried using . Paragraph Format instead but that doesn't really have a method for the coordinates :/

Comment: Can you perhaps post a screenshot of where in a document you're trying to insert the data? It's not clear from your description - you're inserting it into a table, within a table?

Comment: I am essentially inserting the value in an excel cell into a word document; not into a table in the word document

Comment: Oh ...then what's the Rows doing? Is that to determine where *exactly* in the document the data is to go? Can you please post the rest of your code?  What tables are you referring to? Ones in Word or Excel? Please add more detail to your OP for clarity.